# Realtime MathJax Editor

Tags: mathjax

I'm aware of MathJax and MathQuill.

However, I'm wondering if someone has taken MathJax, ripped out the API, and by any chance built a real time math editor out of it?

Thanks!

Comment: @think123 would you care sharing the problems you ran into? I'm considering to try it as well, and it would be interesting to the potential problems.

Comment: @think123 yeah from what I saw so far it really doesn't seem like it would be easy to allow input through MathJax. A copy of your modified MathQuill would be quite cool, thanks! Either publish it on GitHub or, if you prefer, mail it to jan (at) poeschko (dot) com, please.

Comment: I'm scouring the internet for this exact thing (which I've found and have a link to in my history... back in california) it _does_ exist already and is wonderful, I'll come back and post it when I find it, in the meantime does anyone know the library I am referring to?

Comment: @MickLH! What did you see, Mick!!? (https://xkcd.com/979)

Comment: Though seriously, did you ever find the url? Also, why are comments missing in the above exchange?

Comment: I never did find it again :( but MathQuill seems to have matured.

Comment: https://arachnoid.com/latex/